# Desktop Screen Streaming in Java

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture

Can anyone tell me how to stream my desktop through sockets in Java? I tried using screen captures and sending them 1 at a time but it's no good. Too slow! I think to redirect the video stream would be better.

Comment: Which part was slow? Capturing the screen, sending it over the socket or something else?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you want to do this in the first place? There are plenty of solutions for this already built, such as [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) (which also includes a java-client if that's what you want).

If you really want to do the exercise yourself, the major concern should probably be to detect and only send updated areas of the screen and to properly compress the data being sent.